# How to get this code to allow updates?

Tags: trigger

This trigger checks to see if a record that is being inserted or updated is using a role that is already in use and gives the user a notification if it already is in use. The issue is that if one updates the record and tries to save it, it won't allow them because it'll see that the record already exists with that role (like a recursive lookup). How to modify the code that allows saving modifications to the record but not allow one to change the role to a role that already exists?

I hope that this makes sense.

```
trigger trgr_Check_Duplicate_Roles on Key_Staff_People__c (before insert,before update) {


    for (Key_Staff_People__c rsp: Trigger.new) 
        {
            List <Key_Staff_People__c> rcrd = [SELECT Contact__c, Role__c FROM Key_Staff_People__c 
                                                WHERE Contact__c = :rsp.Contact__c AND Role__c = :rsp.Role__c];


            if (rcrd.size() > 0)
            {
                if (rsp.Role__c <> Null && rsp.Role__c <> 'Other')
                {
                    trigger.new[0].addError('A contact with the role "'+rsp.Role__c+'" already Exist. Only the role "Other" may be assigned to multiple Key Staff People.');                    
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you store the ID of a the role in a text field, and make that text field unique?

Comment: Why don't you keep a list of roles before entering the loop and check each new record with the list to see if the role exists or not?

Answer (score 0):

Apex N-u-b. I guess what you are saying the problem is you are updating a record with role__c != null or 'Other' and it gives error.

For that,

try the below code.

```
Set<String> contacts = new Set<String>();
Set<String> roles = new Set<String>();
Map<String, List<Key_Staff_People__c>> roleToKSP = new Map<String, List<Key_Staff_People__c>>();

for(Key_Staff_People__c ksp: Trigger.new) {
    if(!String.isBlank(ksp.Contact__c != null)) {
        contacts.add(ksp.Contact__c);
    }
    if(!String.isBlank(ksp.Role__c)) {
        roles.add(ksp.Role__c);
    }
}
for(Key_Staff_People__c ksp : [SELECT Contact__c, Role__c FROM Key_Staff_People__c 
    WHERE Contact__c IN (contacts) AND Role__c IN (roles)]) {
    if(roleToKSP.containsKey(ksp.Role__c)) {
        roleToKSP.get(ksp.Role__c).add(ksp);
    } else {
        roleToKSP.put(ksp.Role__c, new List<Key_Staff_People__c> {ksp});
    }
}

for(Key_Staff_People__c ksp: Trigger.new) {
    if(ksp.Role__c <> Null && ksp.Role__c <> 'Other' && roleToKSP.get(ksp.Role__c).size() > 1) {
        //Display error message.
    }
}
```

This checks if the record being updated is the second record with the same role. If it is, it will display message. I have not run the code so there may be a minor syntactical error.

Please tell me whether the issue got resolved or not.

Regards,
Jigar

Comment: On this line "   WHERE Contact__c IN (contacts) AND Role__c IN (roles)]) {" it gives the error "expecting a colon, found 'contacts'". What do I need to change?

Comment: Yes, my bad.  It would be WHERE contact__c IN : contacts AND role__c IN : roles.

Comment: I kept getting errors so made change in order to stop errors. It doesn't seem to do the job. I can create doubles.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work out for you I eyeballed it so some adjustments may need to happen..

```
trigger trgr_Check_Duplicate_Roles on Key_Staff_People__c (before insert,before update) 
{
Map<ID, String> kspMap = new Map<ID, String>();

for (Key_Staff_People__c rsp: Trigger.new) 
{
    if(rsp.Role__c != null && rsp.Contact__c != null)
    {
        kspMap.put(rsp.Contact__c, rsp.Role__c);
    }
}

Map<ID, Key_Staff_People__c> alreadyInsertedStaffMap = new Map<ID, Key_Staff_People__c>([SELECT Contact__c, Role__c FROM Key_Staff_People__c WHERE Contact__c != null AND Role__c != null]);
Map<ID, String> contactToKSPMap = new Map<ID, String>();

for(ID ksp : alreadyInsertedStaffMap.keySet())
{
    contactToKSPMap.put(alreadyInsertedStaffMap.get(ksp).Contact__c, alreadyInsertedStaffMap.get(ksp).Role__c);
}

for(ID cToKSPID : contactToKSPMap.keySet())
{
    if(kspMap.containsKey(cToKSPID))
    {
        if(kspMap.get(cToKSPID).Role__c == contactToKSPMap.get(cToKSPID).Role__c)
        {
            Trigger.new[0].addError('A contact with the role "'+ contactToKSPMap.get(cToKSPID).Role__c + '" already Exist. Only the role "Other" may be assigned to multiple Key Staff People.');                    
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I kept getting error on this contactToKSPMap.get(cToKSPID).Role__c so I made it contactToKSPMap.get(cToKSPID) but it only gives an error for a double of the first role. Any other role can save even if it's a double. Role__c is a picklist so the code detects a double for the first value but not any value from #2 and onwards.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with some ideas. It looks like just adding this line makes it work.

```
 if((Trigger.isUpdate && rcrd[0].Role__c <> Trigger.oldMap.get(rsp.Id).Role__c) || Trigger.isInsert)  trigger.new[0].addError('A contact with the role "'+rsp.Role__c+'" already Exist. Only the role "Other" may be assigned to multiple Key Staff People.');
```